# Can Row Level Security(RLS) be applied programmatically in Power BI?

Tags: rest, powerbi, row-level-security

We can apply [Row Level Security (RLS) in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls)  by clicking on the Manage Roles button, but I was wondering if this can also be done programmatically, for example, through a REST API?

Also that article says that there's a known issue where you'll get an error message if you try to publish a previously published report from Power BI Desktop. If its possible to do RLS programmatically, would that issue still remain there and therefore we would have to still do some additional manual step?

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Can-I-update-Row-level-security-via-Rest-API/m-p/1146760